# No wifi adapters found on ubuntu (dual boot with windows10)

Tags: dual-boot, wireless, ubuntu-gnome, ralink

I am stuck on this problem from last 3 days. I installed ubuntu 20 on my windows 10 with dual boot. Everything went well except the wifi is not working. After using ubuntu my wifi led turns red in color, and hence wifi is turned off. I tried 100s of solutions but no luck. In windows wifi is working fine. I checked the instslled wifi adapter and its " Ralink RT3290" in Hp laptop model number 15-r007tx notebook. Futher more i am using bios legacy. I am not getting option for disabling secure boot. Please help me i am so much frustrated.

Solutions i tried:
1:  installing drivers: sudo apt install git build-essential dkms

Git clone -b extented https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new.git

Sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6

sudo modprobe -r rtl8723de && sudo modprobe rtl8723de

2: updating system: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade.

3: disabling power save option in windows power managemnet option.

4: blacklisting hp_wmi: echo "blacklist hp_wmi"> /etc/modprob.d/hp.conf

5: rfkill list: its shows

Phy0: wirless lan
Soft blocked : no
Hard blocked: yes

Then i tried rfkill unblock wifi and rfkill unblock all.

Tried many combinations of function keys fn + f1 to f12. But wifi hardware button still disabled and also airplane mode is now enabled after suspending my laptop.

It seems more hardware button blocked problem than drivers problem.

I hope i have make it clear now. Please any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: We can't tell what you've already tried and whether or not you made a mistake in your attempts without you telling us the details of your attempts and the results of those attempts. Please edit your question and include more details.  Have you searched Ask Ubuntu using the model of your wireless adapter as a search term?

Comment: I think a bug report might be useful, see https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug and file the bug against package linux.  I think if you check in terminal `rfkill list` will show the wifi as hard blocked.  I think you made a typo and your wifi is RT3290 and for some reason I see quite a few HP laptops with this issue lately that have that chipset

Comment: Yes i checked with the rfkill list it was showing hp-wifi soft blocked: no, hard blocked no. Phy0 soft blocked : no , hard blocked : yes. So i tried with the  commands which i checked on askubuntu, to unblock it. Cmd: rfkill unblock wifi etc. But still not working. Again i tried to turn on wifi button( on keyboard ) using some combinations of function keys still nothing happened. I suspended the laptop due to which airplane mode is automatically on now. And there is no option to turn it off as message prompts ( turn off airplane mode using hardware button) tried every button and combination al

Comment: Yes apologies. Adapter is RT3290

Comment: I suggest you help others help you, by being more specific in the list of what you tried. 
1) Replace "etc" with all the rest.
2) Specify the commands/method you used for "disabling power save option". 
3) Post the outcome of each failed attempt (they can fail in many different ways, and providing widely different output).
If you really tried every solution, I guess nobody can help you.

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear. I have added the commands i use may be i skipped here some of commands but mainly i have use these above solution. Thankyou